# Где брать адрес главной и описание сайта на CMS Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Всем привет, решил попробовать написать шаблон для CMS Joomla 3 и вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, подскажите где в Joomla 3 взять адрес главной страницы сайта а также его имя и описание. И где это все вообще хранится?

Comment: Сделал такое $urlsite = &JFactory::getURI(); но этот код выводит адрес текущей страницы,  нужно адрес самого сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php 
    $a = parse_url(JFactory::getURI());
    var_dump($a['host']);
```

OR

https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JFactory_Class

https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JURI

```
<?php 
    &JFactory::getURI()->getHost();
```